# Matplotlib: How to extract vlines and fill_between data from ax objects?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

I have a figure comprised of two x/y curves, a vline and a fill_between in Matplotlib.

My ultimate aim is displaying this figure along with 2 other figures as subplots in a 4th new figure. And I really want to avoid creating all three figures from scratch again just for this new figure with subplots.

So, I'm looking to create a 1x3 figure (subplots, 1 row, 3 columns) like this:

[fig1, fig2, fig3]

I'm almost there. I've so far been able to extract the two x/y curves from the original figure's ax object. Moving through a for loop, I've been able to rebuild most of the three figures as subplots in my new figure:

(ax_a, ax_b, ax_c are ax objects belonging to the three original figures I want to add as subplots to my new figure)

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (16,4))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,3)

for ax, ref in zip(fig.axes, [ax_a, ax_b, ax_c]):
    for line in ref.lines:
        x = line.get_xdata()
        y = line.get_ydata()
        ax.plot(x,y)
    ax.set_xlabel(ref.get_xlabel())
    ax.set_ylabel(ref.get_ylabel())
```

This actually creates a 1x3 grid of my original 3 plots. It's almost perfect.

What's missing are the fill_between component and the vlines component. If I could extract those objects from ax_a, ax_b and ax_c, I'd be done. But I can't find a way to do that.

Is there a way? If not, how would you solve a problem like this?

Thanks so much in advance for any advice offered.

Comment: The recommended way would be to create separate functions for each type of plot. These functions get the `ax` to plot on, together with additional parameters. You just call these functions again for the new plot.  The approach to extract data from already created plots is really not recommended.